# Know the type of a word on Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, token

I'm working on Lucene, as a Newbie and I'm searching a way to find in a tokenstream.
If it's a verb, a name, or other.
I see the method `type()` for the token's class but I'm using the class `CharTermAttribute`.

I have already tried to find a way on the API doc, but i don't found anything for this.

Comment: Lucene doesn't know about verbs or nouns.

Comment: Are you sure about it ? 
Because, with the token class, the lexical type can be returned..

Comment: Lexical types include "word", "eos", and, I would expect "number" etc. Lucene isn't a natural language parser.

Answer (score 1):

@EJP is correct, that Lucene doesn't know anything about parts of speech on it's own.

However, you could implement a custom filter that handles this well.  Lucene's TokenStream API example implementation actually does exactly that.  I'll include a few pertinent bits here, [but also look over the complete example](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html) (starts about halfway down the page).

Two things, in particular, seem of primary interest.  First, creating a custom `PartOfSpeechAttribute` interface extending `Attribute`.  These Attributes are used to attach some attendant data to tokens during analysis.  A simplified version of that provided in the example (again, visit the link above to see their more robust implementation):

```
public class PartOfSpeechAttribute implements Attribute {
  public static enum PartOfSpeech {
    Noun, Verb, Adjective, Adverb, Pronoun, Preposition, Conjunction, Article, Unknown
  }

  private PartOfSpeech pos = PartOfSpeech.Unknown;

  public void setPartOfSpeech(PartOfSpeech pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
  }
}
```

Then you will need to implement your custom filter which adds these attrributes to each Token.

```
public static class PartOfSpeechTaggingFilter extends TokenFilter {
  PartOfSpeechAttribute posAtt = addAttribute(PartOfSpeechAttribute.class);

  protected PartOfSpeechTaggingFilter(TokenStream input) {
    super(input);
  }

  public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    if (!input.incrementToken()) {return false;}
    posAtt.setPartOfSpeech(determinePOS(termAtt.buffer(), 0, termAtt.length()));
    return true;
  }

  // determine the part of speech for the given term
  protected PartOfSpeech determinePOS(char[] term, int offset, int length) {
    // ???
  }
}
```

Then you would be able to extract the `PartOfSpeechAttributes` from the `TokenStream` much like you would any other attribute.

Of course, that doesn't answer how to determine the Part of Speech.  The implementation of `determinePOS` is somewhat beyond the scope I can expect to cover here though.  [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/) might be a good library for making that determination, among others.

There is also some as yet in development work on an [OpenNLP analysis module](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP) that would definitely be work a look, though it doesn't look like parts of speech are handled by it yet, nor that it has got much love in in about a year.

Comment: Wow! Thanks you! Really!
I'm going to try it!